# Do we want copy-paste, or kill-yank?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Surprisingly, we have 5 [copy-paste](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) questions, and only 3 [yank](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yank) questions (no [kill](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill) though).

We should consolidate them. Which version do we prefer?
[copy-paste](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) or [kill-yank](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-yank)? [copy-yank](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-yank)? [copy-kill-yank](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-kill-yank)? [kill-ring](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-ring)?

Is search engine optimization a concern here?

Comment: Just a note: "kill" is not a synonym of "copy".

Comment: @T.Verron True, [tag:copy-yank] then? [tag:copy-kill-yank]? [tag:kill-ring]?

Answer (score 11):

I'd choose [copy-paste](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) for the whole process of copying/cutting and pasting text around, because that's one everybody (both beginners and advanced users) would understand. Tags shouldn't trigger questions.

Another reason is that it could happen that `kill` and `yank` are not the only way, or not the more natural, to achieve the wanted action (for example rectangle regions, CUA functions...).

[kill](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill) and [yank](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yank) can still be used when the question specifically refers to the behavior of the corresponding function.

You didn't ask it, but I don't think we'd need a [cut-paste](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cut-paste) either, this could be synonymized to [copy-paste](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste). After all, "copy" = "cut and paste twice", isn't that how everybody does that? `;)`

Comment: Depends what I'm copying.  If I have already grabbed a specific section of text (mid-line to mid-line) I'll usually remember to copy.  Otherwise it'll usually be `kill`(-line) and then `yank` because I still need it.

Comment: Who uses “cut and paste”? No Stack Exchange site has a [tag:cut-paste] tag. [emacs.se] is the 9th to get a [tag:copy-paste] tag. So yes, [tag:copy-paste] is the way to go, with possible more specialized tags such as [tag:kill-ring].

Answer (score 2):

Use [copy-paste](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste), which is the common layman term, as the main tag. While Emacs reserves *paste* to mean pasting from some operating system clipboard outside Emacs, [copy-paste](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) is the most discoverable tag for most users. The menu nowadays calls the commands *Cut*, *Copy* and *Paste*.

Make [kill](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill) and [yank](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yank) synonyms. While these are the correct Emacs terms, they aren't known outside Emacs (and may even have different meanings).

Some questions may warrant more specialized tags, such as [kill-ring](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-ring) for questions about manipulating the kill ring (e.g. select from menu). Interacting with the OS copy-paste functionality is one such subtopic; there are currently two ([1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/412/copy-and-paste-between-emacs-in-an-x-terminal-and-other-x-applications) [2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/766/add-clipboard-to-kill-ring)) questions about this, tagged [clipboard](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clipboard). I'm not sure if that's the right name, as the difference between [copy-paste](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) and [clipboard](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clipboard) isn't really apparent.

Comment: Those two seem to deal specifically with the interaction between system clipboard and Emacs `kill-ring`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say [copy-kill-yank](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-kill-yank), because it is this how Emacs calls them.