# Tag for interprogram copy-paste

Tags: discussion, tags

Emacs has its own copy-paste facilities (mainly the kill ring) and can also interact with the OS's copy-paste facility. What tag should we use for questions that are specifically about copy-paste between Emacs and other programs? (Or “we don't need one”, but I don't think that's the case.)

Example:

- [Interpretation of tabs in text copied from Emacs and pasted in other programs/editors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/interpretation-of-tabs-in-text-copied-from-emacs-and-pasted-in-other-programs-ed)

(Prior discussion on this general topic: [Do we want copy-paste, or kill-yank?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/do-we-want-copy-paste-or-kill-yank))

Comment: I've been meaning to suggest a general tag for questions about integrating emacs with other software (including the OS itself ). Then we could tag [copy-paste] and [integration]. It might be considered a meta tag, but I've seen a few questions already that would benefit from it.

Comment: @Malabarba [tag:integration] wouldn't be a meta tag, but it wouldn't be a useful tag either: it covers a whole bunch of unrelated things: copy paste, windows/frames, file type associations, package management, key mappings, shells/term, …

Answer (score 2):

We could use the same term that Emacs itself uses: [**interprogram copy/paste**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Kill-Ring.html#Low_002dLevel-Kill-Ring).

But of course those not familiar with this terminology will not think to use that. We might use it as a tag synonym (?).

I'd suggest perhaps **`external-copy-paste`**.

Comment: I have the same reservation about [tag:interprogram-copy-paste], but I think it should exist at least as a synonym, because it's the only one that's easily discoverable. [tag:external-copy-paste] sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html#Clipboard), I suggest `clipboard`.

> The clipboard is the facility that most graphical applications use for “cutting and pasting”. When the clipboard exists, the kill and yank commands in Emacs make use of it.

Comment: I foresee people misusing this to mean the kill-ring. Might we use os-clipboard to reduce the chances of that a little bit?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.  How do we sort things out in meta?  Do you post another answer recommending `os-clipboard` and we see which gets more votes?