# Should we kill or yank some copy-paste tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have multiple tags about copy-paste, I mean about killing and yanking. Should some of them be synonyms? Should some of them be renamed, deleted, or disambiguated?

- [killing](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/killing) (5): only used on questions about kill operations. This is the short title in of the relevant [chapter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing.html#Killing) in the Emacs manual, so in general I'd favor this as the main tag. However, given how Emacs uses different terminology from the rest of the world, and given that “killing” is ambiguous as to whether it only refers to killing or to the whole kill-yank family, I'm inclined to go with standard terminology here.
- [yank](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yank) (26) is more often than not used on questions specifically about the yank side, but also on questions about copy-paste in general.
- [copy-paste](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) (46) is the terminology used by the rest of the world. It has the majority share here as well. So I think this should be the main tag.
- [clipboard](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clipboard) (26) is basically a synonym of “copy-paste” in standard terminology, but in Emacs it specifically refers to the OS facility. In practice [clipboard](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clipboard) does seem to be used specifically about the OS facility, though [this may not be the best name](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199/tag-for-interprogram-copy-paste).
- [kill-ring](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-ring) is mostly used to refer to copy-paste in general. While I can see the value in reserving this tag for questions that are specifically about the kill ring rather than about the operations to get things into it and out of it, this doesn't seem to bear out in practice and anyway it isn't a very clear distinction.

We [had this discussion two years ago](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/do-we-want-copy-paste-or-kill-yank) but it was inconclusive and our tags have evolved naturally since then.

Have I missed some relevant tags? What should each of these tags be about?

Answer (score 3):

1. We should have one tag that covers the general topic of copying, pasting, and cutting: `copy-yank-kill` or `copy-paste-cut` (approximate synonyms). I don't see a need to have tags for these separately.
2. `kill-ring` and `clipboard` need to exist independently of a general `copy-paste-cut` tag.  Similarly to `clipboard`, we can have tags `primary-selection` and `secondary-selection`.  (`selection` is ambiguous and is best avoided, IMO.)
3. `killing` should be removed.  `kill` and `killing` cannot appear alone - we have killing of buffers too.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making `copy-yank-kill` and `copy-paste-cut` synonyms of each other.

Comment: @Anaphory: Yes, that's what I meant too. They should be tag synonyms.